# Sql Select Group By

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Есть таблица "Tickets" c столбцами

SubAgentID в котором хранится ID Клиента

DEALDATE в котором хранится Дата операции

TotalSub в котором хранится сумма

и таблица "Counteragent" с  столбцами

ID в котором хранится ID Клиента

ShortName в котором хранится Имя Клиента

Мой запрос

```
SELECT 
t.DEALDATE as date, t.SubAgentID, c.ShortName as NameSub, ROUND(ISNULL(SUM(t.TotalSub),0),2) as  TotalSub
FROM Tickets as t 
left join Counteragent as c on c.ID=t.SubAgentID
WHERE t.DEALDATE Between '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-02' 
GROUP BY t.SubAgentID, t.DEALDATE, c.ShortName 
ORDER BY t.DEALDATE, c.ShortName asc
```

Мой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать запрос чтобы результат был таким

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

СУБД SQL Server? Может, динамический PIVOT:

1. Выборка дат:

```
-- ограничиваем кол-во столбцов
DECLARE @dateLimiter [datetime] = (
  SELECT MAX(t.[DEALDATE]) AS [latestDate]
  FROM
    [Tickets] t
);
SET @dateLimiter = DATEADD([day], -3, @dateLimiter);

-- генерируем столбцы с датой
DECLARE @dateCols [varchar](max) = STUFF(
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      ', [' + CONVERT([varchar](10), t.[DEALDATE], 120) + ']'
    FROM [Tickets] t
    WHERE
      t.[DEALDATE] > @dateLimiter
    ORDER BY 1
    FOR XML PATH('date'), TYPE
  ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
  1,
  1,
  ''
);
```

2. Выполнение динамической SQL:

```
DECLARE @queryDynamic [varchar](max) = '
  SELECT
    [ShortName] AS [Клиент],
    ' + @dateCols + '
  FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        t.[DEALDATE],
        t.[TotalSub],
        c.[ShortName]
      FROM
        [Tickets] t
        INNER JOIN [Counteragent] c ON c.[ID] = t.[SubAgentID]
    ) t
    PIVOT (
      SUM(t.[TotalSub])
      FOR [DEALDATE]
      IN (' + @dateCols + ')
    ) p
';
EXECUTE(@queryDynamic);
```

Comment: СУБД SQL Server? использую SQL Server-2008

Comment: Куда в запросе поставить WHERE t.DEALDATE Between '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-02' ? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: При генерации столбцов можно указать конкретно на какой диапазон, например, вместо `WHERE t.[DEALDATE] > @dateLimiter` поставить `WHERE t.DEALDATE Between '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-02'`. Судя по картинке результата я думал, что у вас запрос формируется динамически исходя от максимальной даты.

Comment: я поставил ваш запрос информация появляется но суммы по датам другие по клиентам

Comment: оказывается дело в форматировании даты при генерации столбцов. ответ обновил, вас устроит если поля будут в формате `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: да меня устроит формат YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: сделал CONVERT([varchar](10), t.[DEALDATE], 102) все получилось))